# Animation not saved as mp4 using whammy js

Tags: javascript, canvas

I used this js to export everything in my canvas as an mp4 video. I succeeded in exporting it as a video but the video is always 0 in time.

Here's the js I used
https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy

Here's the code I have so far that can download the canvas and elements inside but not the animation.

```
var canvas_video = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
        canvas_video.save();
        console.log(canvas_video);
        var encoder = new Whammy.Video(15);
        var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
        encoder.add(canvas_video);
        console.log("1",encoder);
        encoder.compile(false, function(output){
            //var url = (window.URL || window.URL).createObjectURL(output);
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(output);
            console.log(url);
            document.getElementById('download_link').href = url;
        });
```

When I checked on the console to debug it, it shows encodeFrame 0.

Can anyone advise on what should I do and if I miss something?

Comment: How did you add the video to whammy js? Im trying to merge a canvas with text and a video in the back of it using whammy js but i cant figure out how to add the video.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's still looking for the answer - 
That Library will only output to .webm instead of .mp4.
As far as I know, except for Chrome, no other browser support webm playback. So, use Chrome to view the video. Other browsers will stuck at 0 time.